# Relative to absolute url conversions

Tags: php

I just have learned how to parse an html page and convert its links from relative to absolute. The current plug-in I use can take 1 url and parse it. What if I have some lists of urls which I want to parse together. Is it possible? If yes, I would like to hear some coding suggestions from you.

Here is the way I call my current php class. Thank you

```
$result = PIPHP_GetLinksFromURL("http://example.com");

echo "<ul>";
for ($j = 0 ; $j < count($result) ; ++$j)
   echo "<li>$result[$j]</li>";
```

Comment: How is the list of URL's formated? Knowing this you could easily create something that would list them all.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the same function for another page:

```
$result = PIPHP_GetLinksFromURL("http://example.com");
$result2 = PIPHP_GetLinksFromURL("http://another-example.com");

echo "<ul>";
for ($j = 0 ; $j < count($result) ; ++$j)
   echo "<li>$result[$j]</li>";
echo "</ul>";

echo "<ul>";
for ($j = 0 ; $j < count($result2) ; ++$j)
   echo "<li>$result2[$j]</li>";
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: It's better to just put that in a function that accept a URL and returns an array of links that call it for each URL.